# Add match to the same group when using pipe

Tags: regex

How to make both matches belong to group 1?

***regex:***

```
^.{7}(.*).{4}|(.*).{4}
```

***values:***

```
QOQSNT.ini
QOQSNT_MSSQLSERVER.ini
```

***Result:***

[image]

> Red is Group 1
>
> Green is Group 2

Comment: Try `([^_]+)\.[^.]+$`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j3Tce9/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PCRE and Boost, you can use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
(?|^.{7}(.*).{4}|(.*).{4})
^^^             ^        ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j3Tce9/2).

However, you may also use

```
([^_]+)\.[^.]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j3Tce9/1).

**Details**

- `([^_]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `_`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]+` - 1+ chars other than a dot
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: A doubt, if I need to escape the `\\`, how do I do?

Comment: Example Ansible: `"{{ item | regex_replace('([^_]+)\.[^.]+$', '\\g<1>') }}"`

Comment: @LuisHenrique If you use a string literal, usuallly ``\`` must be doubled. You may also put `.` into a character class, `[.]`. Then, you won't have to escape it. Probably you want to match the whole string, and you may still do it with your regex, `"{{ item | regex_replace('^.{7}(.*).{4}|(.*).{4}', '\g<1>\g<2>') }}"`